# Products of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Having two positive definite matrices $A, B$, it holds that the product $ABA$ is positive definite.

I'm looking for a simple proof of this fact.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps if you tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Also, if this is HW, it should be tagged as such. Regards

Comment: If $B$ is definite positive and $A$ is self-adjoint, then $ABA=C^*C$ with $C=\sqrt{B}A$. So it is definite positive. But the good/minimal answer is given by Dan Shved below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't even need positive definiteness of $A$, it is enough that $B$ is positive definite and $A$ is nonsingular and symmetric. Then for any nonzero column $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ column $Ax$ is also nonzero, therefore
$$
x^T(ABA)x = (Ax)^T B (Ax) > 0.
$$

Comment: In question $B$ is  not symmetric...So how you take $B$ as symmetric ? What happen for any two arbitrary positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 I'm using the definition of a positive-definite matrix as given on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). According to this definition, each positive-definite matrix is symmetric. If, however, you choose to define positive-definite matrices as *any* matrices that have $x^T A x > 0$ for each column $x \neq 0$, then the statement in the question simply becomes false.