# Eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix times a matrix with eigenvalues with positive real part

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $A$ is a positive definite matrix and that $B$ is a matrix whose eigenvalues are complex but have strictly positive real parts. Can it be shown that the eigenvalues of $AB$ also have positive real parts? Is there an easy way to prove this?

Comment: If complex includes strictly real, then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250355/product-of-any-two-arbitrary-positive-definite-matrices-is-positive-definite-or) might be relevant.

Comment: If $B$ is symmetric, then I can show that the above is true. But I am assuming that $B$ is not symmetric...

Comment: Ah right. I realised also the answer in that link would tell you $AB$ need not satisfy $x^T(AB)x > 0$ for $x \neq 0$ but AFAIK this is not a necessary condition for the real parts of the eigenvalues being positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example: $$A = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 2\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1 & 5\cr -1 & 1\cr},\ 
AB = \pmatrix{2 & 4\cr -3 & -3\cr}$$
Then $A$ is positive definite, $B$ has eigenvalues $1 \pm i \sqrt{5}$ with positive real part, but $AB$ has eigenvalues $-1/2 \pm i \sqrt{23}/2$ with negative real part.

Comment: I see. Are then any additional conditions for which the above is true?

Comment: If $B$ is a normal matrix with all eigenvalues of positive real part and $A$ is positive definite, then all eigenvalues of $A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$, and therefore of $AB$, have positive real part.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $B=\pmatrix{3&-5\\ 1&-1}$, whose eigenvalues (namely, $1\pm i$) have positive real parts. Let $A=\pmatrix{t&0\\ 0&1}$ with $t>0$. Since $AB\to\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&-1}$ when $t\to0$, $AB$ has an eigenvalue with negative real part when $t$ is small.